# Use MySQL Queries with Json in express

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, express, backend

Lately I have been searching the internet to use MySQL together with Express. I have been able to make this part running.

My program uses Clusters, consisting of Subclusters, and subclusters consist of Comptences.
Now there is a new problem. Whenever I run the query:

```
select c.clusterName, s.subClusterName, com.competenceName from Clusters c
join SubClusters s on c.clusterID = s.clusterid
join Competences com on s.subClusterID = com.subClusterID
```

I get my jsonformat back as

```
[{
  clusterName: cluster1,
  subClusterName: subcluster1,
  competenceName: competence1
},
{
  clusterName: cluster1,
  subClusterName: subcluster1,
  competenceName: competence2
}]
```

I get how this comes, but now I want to change my JSon format to look like this:

```
[{
  clusterName: cluster1,
  subClusterName: [
    {
      subClusterName: subcluster1,
      competences: [{competenceName: competence1}, {competenceName: competence2}]
  },
  {
      subClusterName: subcluster2,
      competences: [{competenceName: competence1}, {competenceName: competence2}]
  }]
}]
```

I'm also gonna put my code from my backend here, as I am new, I might misused all

**models/Competence.js**

This is the model i've made while searching on the internet on how to make models.
[image]

**routes/competences.js**
[image]

I have been searching for quite a while now. And it would be great if somebody could help me further on this issue. As I am quite new with backend stuff, it's hard to find all the correct things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also another library very useful that you should try, knexjs that I think that is easier to use than sequelize

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using the Sequelize library. It is also a nice way to make your backend code cleaner to work with relational databases